# Remove element from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove a element from an associative array with an string structure.

**Example:**

```
$array = array(
    "one"=>array("Hello", "world"),
    "two"=>"Hi"
)
```

I want to create a function that removes the elements like this:

```
function removeElement($p) {
    // With the information provided in $p something like this should happen 
    // unset($array["one"]["hello"]) 
}

removeElement("one.hello");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base array is associative, the inner array (key `one`) is *not*, its a indexed array, which you can not access via `["hello"]` but rather `[0]`.

You can remove the `hello` value by using the `unset` function, but the indexes will stay as they are:

```
$array = ['Hello', 'World'];  // array(0: Hello, 1: World)
unset($array[0]); // Array is now array(1: World)
```

If you wish to keep unset and keep the array indexes in order, you can fetch the values using the `array_values` function after unset:

```
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($array); // array(0: World)
```

Or you could use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice).

When it comes to using a `string` as key for multidimensional array with a dot-separator I'd recommend taking a look at laravels [`Arr::forget` method](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php#L165) which does pretty much exactly what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a static solution to your question, in any case, you need to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
function removeElement($p, $array) {
    $_p = explode('.', $p);
    return unset($array[$_p[0]][$_p[1]]);
}
```

But bear in mind, this doesn't work if you have more in `$p` (like: `foo.bar.quux`)